# Read from CSV file to publish telemetry data in Gateway using Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, gateway

I 'am trying to read from CSV file and  publish telemetry in gateway using python ,but I did't receive any data in thingsboard i 'am trying like this :

```
def get_template(self):
    template = (open("/home/mohsen/bitbucket/iotgatewayv2/test.csv", "r").read())
    Liste_temp = template.split(";")
    return Liste_temp



def run(self):    # Main loop of thread
    try:
        while True:
            for device in self.__devices:
                # device_serial_port = self.__devices[device]["serial"]
                received_character = bytes('41\r2430947530\n','utf-8')
                template = self.get_template()
                print('****Template******', template)
                data_from_device = b''

                data_from_device = data_from_device + template
                try:
                    converted_data = self.__devices[device]['converter'].convert(self.__devices[device]['device_config'], data_from_device)
                    self.__gateway.send_to_storage(self.get_name(), converted_data)
                    time.sleep(.1)
                except Exception as e:
                    log.exception(e)
                    self.close()
                    raise e
```

Comment: What is the error or what is your question here?

Comment: I didn't received  any data in the thingsboard

Comment: @mohsendifallah do you get any error, have you tried debugging the code?